# How can I get Sandcastle to play nice with SVN?

Tags: svn, sandcastle, robocopy

I'm trying to add the output of a Sandcastle compilation into source control, but Sandcastle has issues trying to output directly into a subversion-controlled directory structure.

So, what I was trying to do is output into a non-controlled directory and then robocopy into the svn-controlled structure. I'd prefer to use /MIR to remove any old files, but the problem is that this causes robocopy to wipe out all the svn property stuff.

So, is there an easy way to use robocopy the way I want, or is there another solution?

Comment: You're limiting yourself to people who know both Sandcastle and Robocopy.  Maybe you could describe this a little more generically.  The only thing strange about a controlled dir is that ".svn" folder.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding robocopy I believe you can use the `/xd` switch to exclude directories, including a directory in your source or destination.  For SVN try telling robocopy to exlude `.svn` folders:

```
robocopy C:\sourcedir\ C:\mydestination /mir /xd .svn
```